# BeginEdit of a specific Cell from code behind

Tags: wpf, datagrid, templates, cell, toolkit

Is possibile begin edit of a specific cell from code behind with DataGrid control (WPF Toolkit)?

I have to enable the celledittemplate of first cell of selected row after a button action...how can I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pls, try putting the code below in your button's on click event handler:

```
    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(1, 0);
    if (cell != null)
    {
        cell.Focus();
        yourDataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
```

below is implementation for the GetCell method taken from here [Grabing controls from a DataGrid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/63974f4f-d9ee-45af-8499-42f29cbc22ae)

```
public DataGridCell GetCell(int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(row);

    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

        // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
            gridPersons.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, gridPersons.Columns[column]);
            cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        }
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public DataGridRow GetRow(int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)gridPersons.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
        gridPersons.ScrollIntoView(gridPersons.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)gridPersons.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: I try and it works! Thank you very much!

Very useful function.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. This code doesn't work for me directly. However, it works only if I call the first few lines from Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, like this: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => StartEditCurrentCell()));