# DataGrid click cell content/text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, cell

So I need the cell text content of the DataGrid cell clicked or doubleclicked. Reading numerous questions I can't seem to see how this task so extremely trivial in WinForms can be done in WPF..?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071321/445533) I found a solution that works at least with .NET 4.5.2 :

```
var element = dg.CurrentColumn == null ? null : dg.Columns[dg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex].GetCellContent(dg.SelectedItem);
var text = element.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) ? ((TextBox)element).Text : null;
Console.WriteLine(text);
```