# Wpf DataGrid - Unable to select cells programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn, datagridcell

I need to select all the cells of a column which header was clicked ,

i took this from the following post :

[Selecting all Cells in Column](https://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Column%20Selection)

when a certain column is clicked i wan't to select all it's respected cells.

cs :

```
    private void OnColumnsClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        var columnHeader = (DataGridColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource;           
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectedCells.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.AssociatedObject.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(this.AssociatedObject.Items[i], columnHeader.Column);
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectedCells.Add(cellInfo); // Here is where the Exception is thrown when adding to the SelectedCells collection .
        }                        
    }
```

the problem is that after adding the second cell to SelectedCells i get the following exception :

```
 The collection already contains the item.
```

Important :

When creating **cellInfo** it has a value for Item and Column properties (See attached image) :

[image]

After adding is to SelectedCells , see **SelectedCells[0]** :

[image]

Any ideas why the Cell is being zero'd after adding it to SelectedCells ?

DataGridCellInfo (struct)  equality check (from reflector):

```
internal bool EqualsImpl(DataGridCellInfo cell)
{
     return (((cell._column == this._column) && (cell.Owner == this.Owner)) && (cell._info == this._info));
}
```

Comment: i found an answer which did select the cells for me : ouflak's answer  

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978119/select-datagridcell-from-datagrid/15758870#comment29588556_15758870