# How can I get the selected range values from my datagrid in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseover

How can I get the selected range values from my datagrid in WPF application?

This is the screenshot of my application.
[image]

And this is my code so far:

```
private void excel_grid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = sender as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
        IList<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo> ne = dataGrid.SelectedCells;

    }
```

Comment: I found the solution [**here**][1] 
It is very fast and reliable :)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764498/wpf-datagrid-programmatically-editing-a-cell