# WPF DataGrid - make column readonly via c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to turn off the isReadOnly property of a WPF Datagrid cell via c#. I need to do this once a user clicks on a row.

I have this so far

```
 private void dgProductItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;

     if (dg != null)
     {
        DataGridRow dgr = (DataGridRow)(dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex));
     }
  }
```

But how do I get down to the cell level via the

> DataGridRow

So finally I am looking for cell.ISReadOnly = false/true;

Cheers

Comment: you want to make column read only?

Comment: I have the column set is read only = true in the XAML, however, on particular rows I want to change this to false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to work on the `DataGridCell` object, you are going to need a little bit more code than expected

[Check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764498/wpf-datagrid-programmatically-editing-a-cell) and use the `TryTofindGridCell` method to retrieve the `DataGridCell` object and then set its `IsreadOnly` property

Alternatively you can also check the [solution described here](http://svgvijay.blogspot.fr/2013/01/how-to-get-datagrid-cell-in-wpf.html) to retrieve `DataGridRow`s / `DataGridCell`

Comment: For Info for others: I used the second link + When you declare isReadOnly on Xaml, to make it not readonly, use cell.IsEditing as cell.isReadOnly is a getter only!